# Flutter: Can I turn off the default animation of images?

Tags: flutter

There is a way to turn off in Flutter the default animation of an image when appears on the screen? I'm thinking that float in from bottom animation of images.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIJyY.gif)

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DelayedDisplay(
          delay: Duration(seconds: 3),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            child: Image.network(
                'https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add some minimal code to recreate what you are facing?

Comment: Add code. I have no idea how did you achieve animated image without using any animation...

Comment: I found the solution, the DelayedDisplay has a fadingDuration property which is 800 milliseconds by default. If I set it to 0 then the animation is gone.